# Using parameter 1 without using parameter 0 in Spring Boot messages

Tags: spring, spring-internationalization

In `messages.properties` file:

```
validation.title=At least {1} characters
```

Also `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is defined:

```
@Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
```

When I run the code I get the result:

```
At least {1} characters
```

But if I change in properties:

```
validation.title=At least {1} characters {0}
```

I get the result:

```
At least 20 characters title
```

But I do not need the `0` parameters.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The arguments are indexed as in an array, and the first argument is 0 and not 1. Do it like `At least {0} characters`, and it should work.

Comment: It is array of 2 elements, first is `title` and second is `6`, so I need the second parameter and I use `{1}`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access array parameters and with this approach in order to get that done and have your string interpolated you need to use the one at the index 0 and I have no idea why. There's another way though and with common annotations (haven't tried this with custom annotations) for validating forms this can be solved as follows:

```
// the form

public class SomeForm {

  @Length(min = 4, max = 16, message="{username.length.error}")
  private String username;

// other stuff
```

}

In the messages.properties

```
username.length.error = Username cannot be blank and its length must be between {min} and {max} characters.
```

So in the message.properties (in this case {min} and {max}) the placeholders must match the names of the params you have on the annotation.